# Membership remote connection string working in SQL Server Management Studio but not in ASP.NET(error 26)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, connection-string

I have a problem with changing the default membership connection string of ASP.NET to a remote one. Here is the connection string I am trying use:

```
Data Source=myserver.com;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=database_name;User ID=username;Password=password
```

The database is hosted on a shared hosting and IS accessible with SQL Server Management Studio and I also tested the exact same connection string with the notepad method and so on...

So, I am almost sure the problem is not my connection string but something else in the `web.config`. Here is the `web.config` file:

http://pastebin.com/JsATXqW7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" />
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="RemoteDB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
          applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager>
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="RemoteDB" applicationName="/"
          name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="RemoteDB" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SkypeSpammerWeb-20121018205959;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SkypeSpammerWeb-20121018205959.mdf" />
    <add name="RemoteDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx.com;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

And here is a screenshot of the error I am getting:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/3vd3dbahf/]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add ...
```

I also notice that your connection string has `Data Source=xxxxxxx.com`, I assume you just blocked that out for posting, but does it really end in .com?  Are you certain the fully qualified .com address is resolveable from your web server?

Comment: The address does end in .com and I am sure it is working because I tested it with Sql Management Studio

Comment: Thank you this worked correctly and now I can use the membership feature no problem but there is one more problem: when I go to the Asp.Net Web Site Administration Tool and try to test the AspNetSqlProvider it fails and gives me the following error:Could not establish a connection to the database. 
If you have not yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the provider.

Comment: ...and also yes -  register and login DO work so I am not sure why is that error...

Comment: @user1757695 - There's something goofy here.  You're using the Universal providers (DefaultMembershipProvider) but you are mentioning AspNetSqlProvider.  You seem to be mixing up your configurations.

Comment: That's possible.. as I mentioned in the first post I am not really good at configurations... and hell I am not sure why is that even in the Configuration Tool as a provider but it IS there..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove "Integrated Security=True", I don't think the shared host will use your windows account and password.